# WPF show "dummy" control until focused/clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I have a list of heavy `Controls`, which I don't want to render before the user interacts with them (one at a time).
I want to show a placeholder for each `Control` until the placeholder is clicked (preferably focused) and then render the real `Control`.

What I've tried looks like this:

```
            <ContentControl x:Name="theControl">
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBlock" Text="Placeholder right here."/>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=TextBlock}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Grid x:Name="theGrid">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="CodeColumn"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock>Heavy control part1</TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">heavy control part2</TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
```

Anyone knows a better approach or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general idea of what I managed to get working.

```
public partial class PlaceHolder : UserControl
{
    private bool m_isReadOnly;
    private object m_PlaceholdeContent;
    private bool m_hasValue;
    private object m_realContent;

    public PlaceHolder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GotFocus += OnGotFocus;
    }

    private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        GotFocus -= OnGotFocus;
        if (!RealContentIsUsed)
        {
            RealContentIsUsed = true;
            Content = RealContent;
        }
    }

    private bool RealContentIsUsed { get; set; }

    public object RealContent
    {
        get { return m_realContent; }
        set
        {
            m_realContent = value;
            if (IsReadOnly || HasValue)
            {
                Content = m_realContent;
            }
        }
    }

    public object PlaceholdeContent
    {
        get { return m_PlaceholdeContent; }
        set
        {
            m_PlaceholdeContent = value;
            if (!RealContentIsUsed)
            {
                Content = m_PlaceholdeContent;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return m_isReadOnly; }
        set
        {
            m_isReadOnly = value;
            if (value && !RealContentIsUsed)
            {
                Content = RealContent;
                RealContentIsUsed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get { return m_hasValue; }
        set
        {
            m_hasValue = value;
            if (HasValue && RealContentIsUsed == false)
            {
                Content = RealContent;
                RealContentIsUsed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a *better* solution, but you can create the heavy control in code and then remove/add children after a GotFocus event.

Add a GotFocus event to your TextBlock and put the TextBlock in a Grid

```
        <Grid Name="myGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBlock" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Text="Placeholder right here." GotFocus="TextBlock_GotFocus" />
        </Grid>
```

Then in the cs file

```
    private void TextBlock_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        createNewControl();
    }

    private void createNewControl()
    {
        Grid myOtherGrid = new Grid();

        RowDefinition newRow1 = new RowDefinition();
        newRow1.Height = new GridLength(100.0);
        RowDefinition newRow2 = new RowDefinition();
        newRow2.Height = new GridLength(100.0);

        ColumnDefinition newColumn1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        newColumn1.Width = new GridLength(50.0);
        ColumnDefinition newColumn2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        newColumn2.Width = new GridLength(50.0);

        myOtherGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow1);
        myOtherGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow2);
        myOtherGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(newColumn1);
        myOtherGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(newColumn2);

        TextBox myOtherTextBlock1 = new TextBox();
        myOtherTextBlock1.Text = "new block 1";

        TextBox myOtherTextBlock2 = new TextBox();
        myOtherTextBlock2.Text = "new block 1";

        myOtherGrid.Children.Add(myOtherTextBlock1);
        Grid.SetRow(myOtherTextBlock1, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(myOtherTextBlock1, 0);

        myOtherGrid.Children.Add(myOtherTextBlock2);
        Grid.SetRow(myOtherTextBlock2, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(myOtherTextBlock2, 1);

        myGrid.Children.Remove(TextBlock);
        myGrid.Children.Add(myOtherGrid);
    }
```

Comment: I should mention that I removed all the content control stuff from your original xml example and just had a grid that contained the original TextBlock.

Comment: Kinda, works, though I would like my view to be in properties. ( Did it in my answere)